# How can one get this value of a span with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, key-value

If we have this `span`, how can I get the value of `sip`, i.e. `john.doe@xyz.de`

```
<span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10">
      <img name="imnmark" title="" showofflinepawn="1" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" alt="User Presence" sip="john.doe@xyz.de" id="imn_1,type=sip">;                  
 </span>
```

Right now I use

```
var projectLeaderName = $('#projectLeader span').html();
```

to get the entire value of the span, but I don't know how to get the value of `sip` with jQuery.

I don't think this screenshot is necessary, but I'll add it for completion:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jQuery.attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value of an attribute:

```js
var projectLeaderName = $('span img').attr('sip');
console.log(projectLeaderName);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ms-spimn-presenceWrapper ms-imnImg ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10">
      <img name="imnmark" title="" showofflinepawn="1" class="ms-spimn-img ms-spimn-presence-disconnected-10x10x32" src="/_layouts/15/images/spimn.png?rev=23" alt="User Presence" sip="john.doe@xyz.de" id="imn_1,type=sip">;                  
 </span>
```